# Identify a balloon accident in the 90s or 2000s

Tags: accidents, balloon

I recall hearing about a balloon accident on a news programme on TV in the 90s or 2000s. From memory it was some sort of record attempt, and the last telemetry from the flight indicated that the gondola was in free-fall.

I seem to recall a crew of at least two people. I think it happened over the sea, certainly far from where anyone could observe it, hence the need to rely on radio for communication with the crew and telemetry.

At the time of the report it wasn't know exactly what happened or the fate of the crew, but the free-fall telemetry made it sound pretty bad.

Can anyone identify this accident?

Comment: Any more information? Such as the country it happened in?

Comment: @Jamiec yes, it was over the sea I think. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: *which* sea? There is a lot of sea on the planet!

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of [Steve Fossett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Fossett) who successfully circumnavigated the world in a balloon but then disappeared (never to be found) while flying a light aircraft over the nevada desert?

Comment: Maybe you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelir_Ant%C3%B4nio_de_Carli) accident? It fits every information you gave except the free fall.

Comment: @Jamiec You're exaggerating a little.  Fosset's crash site and remains were found in 2008.

Comment: @ZeissIkon You're right - that was from memory and my memory was wrong.

Comment: @Jamiec definitely wasn't Fossett

Comment: @Bianfable not that I think. I've been through Wikipedia's list of balloon accidents and notable balloon aircraft and didn't find it.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without more details.

Comment: Another morbid thought - hope you're not confusing this with the [challenger accident](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23675/how-long-did-the-crew-of-the-space-shuttle-challenger-survive). Negative for "balloon" but positive for "freefall", "telemetry", "over water", "record" (first teacher in space) and (horribly) "crew"!

Comment: @Jamiec maybe... I would have been very young but it's possible that there was something about the investigation after the fact that I saw.

Answer (score 1):

P 15 of this link describes an incident on July 20 1990 where an unmanned scientific balloon project accidentally experienced a freefall of the payload from 120,000'.  Any chance that what you are remembering was this, or something similar?

http://hdl.handle.net/2060/19910006317

> The 1990 calibration actually consisted of two flights,
>   one on July 20, 1990 and the other on September 6, 1990.
>   A malfunction occurred during the first flight, which
>   resulted in a complete loss of data and a subsequent free fall
>   of the payload from _ 120,000 ft which bent up the tracker
>   assembly and destroyed several cell modules. The tracker
>   was rebuilt, several cells were replaced, and the refurbished
>   payload was flown again in September.

Comment: I've edited in the relevant part from pp15 - links (and especially pdf's) tend to move/get removed so it is good to quote the relevant portions of text that constitute your answer.

Comment: It was definitely manned, but thanks anyway.